# Find date, given WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find a way of finding a date value, given the WEEKNUM and WEEKDAY

For example

```
WEEKNUM = 9
WEEKDAY = 4   '(Wednesday)
```

I can use the below function to find the WEEKNUM from the date, but how can I go the other way around?

```
Function WEEKNUM(D As Date, FW As Integer) As Integer
     WEEKNUM = CInt(Format(D, "ww", FW))
End Function
```

Comment: It may not be possible in all cases, For example in 2016, *WEEKNUM* #1 consists of only two days:  Friday January 1st and Saturday January 2nd.

Comment: You will also have to specify the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a table on a hidden sheet, and just used Vlookup to find the correct date. EG

```
DATE          WEEKDAY     WEEK NO    WEEKDAY + WEEK NO
01/03/2016    Tuesday     Week 10    Tuesday 10
02/03/2016    Wednesday   Week 10    Wednesday 10
```

In VBA, you could then look up the name of the sheet, which is the weekday, and got the week number from the filename of the workbook, then use vlookup to find the correct date.

```
weekNum = Mid(ThisWorkbook.Name, 6, 2)
searchStr = ActiveSheet.Name & " " & weekNum & " " & Format(Now(), "YYYY")
rowNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(searchStr, Sheets("WEEKLIST").Range("D:D"), 0)

strSubject = Format(Sheets("WEEKLIST").Range("A" & rowNo).Value, "DD/MM")
```